# Can I reuse/call existing API in Selenium-Java Framework into the Protractor Framework?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Please bear with me if this is a silly question. But thought of getting an idea.

We have a very sophisticated Selenium Webdriver-Java framework. But now some parts of our application is being implemented in AngularJS. We would like to use protractor for test automation. But we have some API in the existing framework which we would like to reuse. Is there a possibility to do so or do we need to re-write all the existing API in protractor?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not probably the answer you are looking for. But, this can give you some hope.

Unfortunately there is no `protractor java port` at this moment. I use `Selenium C#` and my project started using some `Angular` recently. And, fortunately, there is a [Protractor-net](https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net) project done by some great people to accomplish same thing you are struggling with. I must say, if your project is big enough to leverage some time to write a `java` port for protractor you can follow this project easily. It's not that extensive. I am personally using it and started writing about this on my [blog](https://letmedothat.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/meet-ngwebdriver-handling-driver-instances/)

Answer (score 2):

Some one is trying to develop jProtractor - An angular/protractor implementation for Java Selenium API. https://github.com/caarlos0/jProtractor

This is still under development(not in a position to use yet), but this could be the right tool for people who are in similar situation as me.

Comment: At the time of writing the last commit is from July 2014, i.e., 8 months ago, so the project seems a bit stalled at the moment.