# Using Protractor in the existing java based Selenium Webdriver framework

Tags: java, selenium, frameworks, protractor

I have been working with Selenium Webdriver for creating a Keyword based framework (separate file for object locators, test case in excel file, creating reports using log4j., etc). I like the clarity in managing objects, TCs/Scenarios, reports, etc. in separate files. It also helps, as anyone else who is non tech., can write TCs.

My question here is, 
1. Can I use Protractor with my existing Java based Selenium webdriver framework ? 
2. Will it add value? Will the features or benefits of using Protractor be lost in this fashion?
3. Also, which is better: Selenium based Java framework or protractor?
4. Can we call the protractor js functions from selenium java based framework?

My question is similar to [Can I reuse/call existing API in Selenium-Java Framework into the Protractor Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132097/can-i-reuse-call-existing-api-in-selenium-java-framework-into-the-protractor-fra) . Just wanted to know if this is possible now. I couldn't post on that thread due to some restrictions. I am new here and don't have 50 reputation points, yet.